# (Haskell) Installing hsc3 in KXStudio (Ubuntu)

Tags: haskell, ubuntu, supercollider

I'm trying to install `hsc3` following this tutorial:
http://rd.slavepianos.org/?t=hsc3-texts&e=lhs/hsc3-tutorial.lhs

But I get this error:

> Sound/SC3/UGen/Type.hs:482:5:
>       `bitSizeMaybe' is not a (visible) method of class`Bits'
>
> Failed to install hsc3-0.16
>   cabal:
>
> Error: some packages failed to install:
>   hsc3-0.16 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
>   ExitFailure 1

Tried both the `"cabal install hsc3"` method and downloading from the `darcs` repository.

> GHC --version is 7.6.3

I'm probably missing something trivial.

Comment: bitSizeMaybe is only present after base 4.7.0.0 - ghc 7.6.3 comes with base  4.6. I would say this is a majour error on the library implementors part. There may be an older version of hsc3 that was intended to work with ghc 7.6.3 - you could try that. Otherwise, you'll have to edit the source code or update ghc.

Comment: Thanks, I'd never have guessed!
I managed to install ghc 7.8, but both cabal and the terminal still access 7.6 - how do you uninstall a specific version of ghc?

Comment: If you've installed the Haskell Platform, it comes with an uninstaller (at least on windows). The simplest way is to just delete the ghc and cabal directories.